# Using indvars optimization pass for finding canonical induction variable in llvm/opt

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang

I am trying to obtain the canonical induction variable for a loop in a loop pass, given its reference L*, using L->getCanonicalInductionVariable().

But many of the loops I encounter are not in canonical form. For ex:

```
for (int i = 10; i < 20 ; i++) {
    ....
}
```

According to llvm documentation http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#indvars-canonicalize-induction-variables) , using the "indvars" pass in "opt" should do the trick by converting the loops induction variable into canonical form. I have tried running:

```
opt -mem2reg -indvars < test.bc > optTest.bc
```

where "test.bc" is a bit code format of the for-loop above. But the indvars pass seems to have no effect ( I have omitted the assembly code here, but I have checked it).

Later, using L->getCanonicalInductionVariable() returns null. I have also tried using "indvars" with other passes like "loops", "loop-simplify" but to no avail.

Any idea on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using an LLVM version earlier than r153260, you can enable induction variable rewrite by adding the `-enable-iv-rewrite` command-line option, and it should generate the result you expect to see.

This option has been deprecated since 3.0 and altogether removed after the above-mentioned version; and without it, the pass does not behave according to its documentation. If you want to do it now, then, I think you have to add a pass to implement it yourself - though you can of course use the old (removed) code as reference. I believe that it was removed because (1) more passes were changed to be able to handle loops without a canonical induction variable and (2) the canonization led to other performance impacts; so I guess it would be wise to think twice before adding a similar pass.

Comment: I had tried that earlier, but opt complained that there was no such option. I am using llvm/opt 3.2. Do you know if it has been removed recently?
     opt -mem2reg -indvars -enable-iv-rewrite < test.c > optTest.c
    opt: Unknown command line argument '-enable-iv-rewrite'.  Try:    'opt -help'
    opt: Did you mean '-enable-tail-merge'?

Comment: @RakeshVarna you're right - I have been looking at an older version of the code. I did some checking and reading and updated my answer accordingly, though I don't think you're going to like my new bottom-line, which is "you can't currently use indvars for that".

Comment: Oh ok, Thanks! This is for a project, so I guess I will just implement it myself. Thanks for the info. I cannot upvote since I do not have enough reputation points.

Comment: @RakeshVarna Hey I too need the pass. Did you end up writing it yourself?

Comment: @Oak I was wondering if you know on how can I implement it? I am stuck on that part for my project.